# how do I dismiss my progress dialog after the needed function in alert dialog is applied?

Tags: android, android-view, android-alertdialog, android-progressbar, android-runonuithread

I have a link in my fragment, which shows " click to open dialog" ,upon clicking it, an alert dialog pops up, showing " do you want to change the view? " with yes and no notations. If I click no, nothing happens and dialog dismisses as expected. However, If I click yes, how do call a function to refresh my view and until my view is refreshed show a progress dialog? Here's my code so far, I dont know where to dismiss the progress dialog or make sure the view is refreshed, any clues? :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Are you sure you want to refresh your view?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //refreshview here ? 

                ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "",
                        "Loading. Please wait...", true);
                progressDialog.show();

                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: add `dialog.dismiss();` line in `onClick` of `PositiveButton`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use `AsyncTask` here and in `onPostExecute(...)` dismiss your `Progress Dialog`

Take a look demos

1. [Official Page](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
2. [Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Once you get data refresh your `View` in `onPostExecute(...)`

### Edit:

```
 //Progress Dialog Show logic here
 Runnable r=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Dismiss the Dialog and refresh your Views
        }
    };

    new Handler().postDelayed(r,10*1000);
```

This code is execute after 10 sec.

Comment: is there no easier way of doing this without asynctask based on my current code?

Comment: @JusticeBauer yes another way is by using `Handler`.

Comment: can you show me how to use it with respect to my code?

Comment: @JusticeBauer But let me clear one thing is your new data coming from server to refresh view ?

Comment: no its not, i want to refresh the view locally as in load it again upon clicking "yes" on the alert screen

Comment: @JusticeBauer wait let me provide the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105380/discussion-between-m-d-and-justice-bauer).

Comment: @SOReadyToHelp any idea about my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598276/how-do-i-pass-a-multi-part-body-parameter-for-rxjava2-androidnetworking-post-req ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are not doing any operation on new thread no need for handler. Just call a method like:

```
private void updateView(ProgressDialog dialog){
   //UPDATE
   if(dialog != null){
     dialog.dismiss();
   } 
}
```